# Python: How to convert a list to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, i have a list below,

```
['Visa', 'Rogers', 'Visa']
```

if i want to convert it to a list of tuples, like

```
[('Visa',), ('Rogers',), ('Visa',)]
```

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [(x,) for x in ['Visa', 'Rogers', 'Visa']]
[('Visa',), ('Rogers',), ('Visa',)]
```

simple list comprehension will do the trick. make sure to have the `,` to specify single item tuples (you will just have the original strings instead)

Answer (score 2):

Doing some kind of operation for each element can be done with [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = ['Visa', 'Rogers', 'Visa']

b = [(v,) for v in a]
c = map(lambda v: (v,), a)

print(b) # [('Visa',), ('Rogers',), ('Visa',)]
print(c) # [('Visa',), ('Rogers',), ('Visa',)]
```

Please keep in mind that 1-element-tuples are represented as `(value,)` to distinguish them from just a grouping/regular parantheses